# Print submitted input value in page

Tags: jsp

```html
<label for="recs">Search picture</label><br>
<input type="text" id="recs" name="recs" value="${reco}" style="width: 292px; "/>
```

This is what I am using for accepting a value into the text box. How do I print the submitted value into the web page?

Comment: <label for="recs">Search charater</label><br>
<input type="text" id="recs" name="recs" value="${reco}"/>

Comment: okay. Hi. This question is very simple and should not be asked, but I will answer, for printing out you most of the times write `document.write (<variable name>)` In order to get the value it can be done in many ways, in Javascript it can be done using DOM. 
But you need some kind of trigger for printing out value, google events in javascript or go to w3schools u will get it.

Comment: Are you confident that you aren't confusing Java/JSP with JavaScript?

Comment: thank you. learning stage. Ws told do not hesitate to ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting the form, you mean? Just get it from the [request parameter map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) `${param}` using the parameter name as key (the input field name becomes the request parameter name).

```
${param.recs}
```

Beware of [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) however. Use either JSTL `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()` to HTML-escape it.

```html
<c:out value="${param.recs}" />
```

Note that [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)/[JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) have **nothing** to do with [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: <% out.println(request.getParameter("reco")); %>

Comment: No, that's [oldschool way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Just use `${param.reco}`. You were already using EL in your code, so why falling back to legacy *scriptlets*? Note that your initial question isn't using `<input name="reco">` anywhere. My answer is just targeted on your initial question.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following:
<%= reco %>
this will print the value

Comment: <% out.println(request.getParameter("reco")); %>

Comment: This answer doesn't print the submitted request parameter.

Comment: @Bala: I'm not talking about your comment, but about sheidaei's answer.